# CocoaPods でインストールしたライブラリを特定のファイルでインポートできない

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

CocoaPodsでAPIKitというライブラリをインストールしました。しかし、あるファイルでは正常にインポートできますが、あるファイルだとインポートの箇所に`Cannot load underlying module for 'APIKit'`というエラーが出ます。

問題のあったファイルは下記のファイルです。

```
import UIKit
import APIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var postButton: UIButton!

    private var questions: [Question] = []
    private let maxResult = 40

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func getQuestions(page: Int)-> [Question]{
        let request = IndexQuestion(page: page, maxResults: self.maxResult)
        Session.sendRequest(request){ result in
            switch result{
            case .Success(let questions):
                debugPrint(questions)

            case .Failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

クリーンやビルドもしましたが直りませんでした。原因がわかれば教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。